# How to deduce and overlay variable framerate of video with duplicate frames using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, framerate

I have a lossless video recording of a game without screen tearing. The video itself is at a constant 60fps, but the game framerate varies between 20-30 fps due to performance issues we are debugging. We can overlay an FPS counter within the game, but this impacts the performance and gives an inaccurate picture of what the true achievable framerate is. Is there a way to instead use ffmpeg to deduce the framerate from the duplicate frames in the video file and produce a new video file with the deduced framerate or frame times overlaid?

From some research I have found that `ffmpeg -i lossless.mkv -vf "mpdecimate=hi=0:lo=0:frac=0" -loglevel debug -f null -` will print out a list of all the duplicated frames correctly, but this isn't very useful and might take complicated scripting to convert into the desired result. If there is a way to first convert the video into variable framerate by combining the duplicate frames and then to overlay this framerate over the video, that would be more ideal.

In my testing I have tried this combination of commands:

- `ffmpeg -i lossless.mkv -vf "mpdecimate=hi=0:lo=0:frac=0" -vsync vfr -r 60 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 0 -c:a copy lossless-vfr.mkv`
- `ffmpeg -i lossless-vfr.mkv -vsync vfr -r 60 -vf "drawtext=fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf':x=10:y=10:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:text='frametime\=%{expr\:pkt_duration}'" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 0 -c:a copy lossless-fps.mkv`

However, the displayed frametime always shows the same value in the overlay of 0.016000 despite the variable framerate. If I run `ffprobe -show_frames lossless-vfr.mkv` I see that the `pkt_duration_time` value does vary from one frame to another, so it's weird that it is getting a constant value when drawing the text overlay. How can I get an accurate overlay of the variable framerate?